# Startup of Winforms program 10x slower under x64 relative to x86

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, x86, 64-bit

I've created a popular Winforms program in C# which has a lot of GUI widgets, and found that when the platform target is x64, startup is around 5-10x slower than x86. Under an x64 target, it takes around 5 seconds to start up, and this negatively impacts the user experience. I'd like to make it quicker.

I also tried with another program of mine, and also found the startup time under x64 was double or triple that of x86.

So I began to wonder what was causing it. My programs use quite a lot of widgets, so to test the theory I decided to create a test project with 800 buttons! I set all of them to `Visible=False` so that redrawing/refresh speed doesn't muddy the waters.

[image: Sample form with 800 buttons]

To my amazement, the x64 started up a LOT slower than the x86 equivalent. I then proceeded to time the `InitializeComponent();` section and sure enough, the x64 version ran in about 3.5 seconds. The x86 on the other hand took only around 0.275 seconds. That's almost 13x quicker!

.NET Framework 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5 are equally as bad. Targeting .NET 4 & 4.5 under x64 is much better at around 0.8 seconds, but that's still about 3x as slow (x86 is about as good at 0.28 seconds), and I want to use .NET 3.5 for the increased userbase.

So my question is: What's causing the x64 version to start up so slow, and how can I make it quicker so that it's comparable to the x86 version?

If anyone wants to test immediately, I have created a zip of the VS 2010 project which can be downloaded here: http://www.skytopia.com/stuff/64_vs_32bit_Startup_Speed.zip

Comment: One performance difference between 32 and 64 bit is that the 64 JITter takes longer to compile (but produces better code). But I consider it very unlikely that your code is limited by JIT performance, so that shouldn't be the cause of your performance problem. The new RyuJIT improves 64 bit JIT time, but produces worse code than the current 64 bit JITter.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Interesting. I'm determined to get to the bottom of this one. It's very reproducible, and has a big impact for so many users and developers.

Comment: Targetting .net 4.5 instead of 3.5 improves performance from 2.0 seconds to 1.3 on my machine.

Comment: It might actually be the JIT overhead, if I replace your 10000 line designer file with a loop it becomes much faster.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Oh, did you create a button array for that? And doesn't the designer file get overwritten every time one edits the form in the GUI Design WYSIWYG editor (unfortunately rendering such optimizations very temporary and pointless)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the JIT cost of your 10000 line `InitializeComponent` function.

- If you measure the time between the call to `InitializeComponent` and the execution of its first line, that's the majority of the cost. (Just insert a line at the top of `InitializeComponent` for the measurement.)
- If you use the VS Performance Analyzer, it'll show most time spent in `ThePreStub`, which is related to JIT.
- The 64 bit JITter takes longer to compile code than the 32 bit JITter, but in exchange it produces better code.

  Microsoft is working on new version of the JITter, called RyuJIT. It's derived from the 32 bit JITter and has similar characteristics (fast compilation outputting worse code). It will become the standard JIT in future versions of .NET.
- .NET 4.5 reduces cost from 2.0 seconds to 1.3 on my machine. This is probably due to JIT improvements in the 4.0 runtime.
- An equivalent loop is *much* faster than your `InitializeComponent` function.

  That won't help you if you want to create all components in the designer, but if you have a mix of repetitive controls and components that you want to edit in the designer, you can use a loop. Just put it in `Form1.cs` not in `Form1.designer.cs` so that it won't get overwritten by the designer.
- Using NGen on your assembly should eliminate the JIT cost. But it comes with the downside of having to deal with the GAC.

Comment: You could also use NGen to eliminate the JIT cost.

Comment: NGen is the simple solution, takes it from ~1400 down to ~170 msec on my machine.

Comment: All good points. But editing the designer.cs code directly with for/loop optimization is academic because it reverts as soon as I adjust something in the WYSIWYG Design editor. .NET 4.5 is indeed much faster, but I think I want .NET 3.5 for the larger userbase. RyuJIT sounds great, but isn't out yet, and NGen has compromises as you've pointed out. Is there any 'hack' around this somehow?

Comment: @HansPassant: I made sure to try and avoid any trace of XY this time ;)

Comment: @DanW I only suggested putting a measurement point in `Form1.designer.cs`. Doesn't matter if that reverts, since it's only used to demonstrate that JIT is indeed responsible. If you want to create components programatically, do so in `Form1.cs`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Yes sorry, I realized that - my point was I probably need to use the WYSIWYG editor for sanity's sake, so coding the widgets manually (perhaps just after the InitializeComponent() method) is unfortunately not possible for me.

Comment: @DanW Coding manually only improves the situation if it significantly reduces the size of the code, e.g, when you have a grid of buttons you can create in a loop.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Yes, you made me aware of that previously too, but thanks for clarifying anyway. Out of interest, I tried programmatically cycling through all the buttons using a foreach loop JUST to set the BackColor property, and that brought it from 3.5s to 2.5s alone! Anyway, thanks for the answer - any long term solution will probably involve RyuJIT I think :)